# Calling popToRootViewControllerAnimated from a modal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a modal that I am calling presentModalViewController to display from a custom menubar. This menubar is overlaying a viewcontroller that is pushed from a tableView cell.

Now... that all being said, I need to find some way to jump the user back to the root of the tableView from the modal screen. Is this possible? I've been fighting with this for the past couple of hours with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're starting from a tablview, drilling down to a detail view via a navigation controller, and then presenting a modal view controller on top of that detail view, you'd have two steps to get back to your list/tableview: First you'd dismiss your modal view controller, then you'd pop your detail view off your navigation stack.

That should put you back where you started (at the tablview), if I'm reading this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to the navigation controller to the modal view, and then immediately after calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, you can use the reference to the navigationController to pop back to the root view controller.